# Please make [google-inbox] a synonym of [inbox-by-gmail]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

The official name of the product is *Inbox by Gmail*, but it is often called "Google Inbox". (The URL of `inbox.google.com` exacerbates this a bit.)

Please make [google-inbox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-inbox) a synonym of [inbox-by-gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inbox-by-gmail) and merge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd suggested the synonym.. I've approved it.